# Filtering a Dataframe using two dataframes with different labels using Python Pandas

Tags: python

I have two data frames with different labels df1 and df2.

df1 contains (amongst other things) the starting sequence number, df2 contains (amongst other things) the ending sequence number.

For Example:

> df1['seq_num'] = 1111 and df2['seq_num'] = 4444

I got another data frame with all the transactions including the sequence number and would like to filter the values between df1['seq_num'] and df2['seq_num']. Tried the below code:

`result_df = trans_df['seq_no'].between(df1['seq_no'],df2['seq_no'],inclusive=True)`

but I am getting the following error:

> 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'

Any ideas how to resolve this error or how to achieve the result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more information to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Could you provide more details of your data frames. I was getting a similar error and found that the problem was having different indexes in the data frames i was comparing, but i would need to have more information of your data to know whether my case is similar to yours.